# Building a nodejs addon without modifying C library

Tags: node.js, c, electron, node-modules, node-gyp

I have searched a lot here about the steps to create a add-on for a C library. I see there are plenty of tutorials online on how to build a add-on using the node-gyp. All of them involved creating a .cc file which is built by the node-gyp. Is there a way to build .c files directly as well. I do have a custom c library (.c, .h and also a compiled .dll for the same files). Is there a way to directly use the functions from the custom library without making any modifications to the source files? Most of the examples online have the v8 and uv header files included in it. The C library I have is a more generic and cannot be modified by me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I did try to use node-ffi but it doesnt seem to be working with the newer versions of node-js.

Thanks,

Comment: You will need some sort of wrapper interface layer between your plain C function and nodejs that handles passing arguments to/from your functions.  You can build your own wrapper layer that "uses" your C library without modifying the C library itself.